# Disallow to login without domain

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Is it possible to configure WSO2 to not allow logins without domain?
e.g.

> **Primary/username** - allow
>
> **username** - disallow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Chamila mentioned the solution would be to write a custom component. However user operation listener won't work because by the time it reaches the listeners the domain is processed and dropped from the user name.

So, it should be a Custom Userstore manager extending your current User store manager. Refer [this page](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Writing+a+Custom+User+Store+Manager) and write a custom userstore manager (Extending the current user store manager will make things easier) and then override its `authenticate(String,Object,boolean)` method to check the domain name's existence prior to calling `super(String,Object,boolean)`. Refer the same page for details in deploying the custom user store manager.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't do this just by changing a configuration. But you can create a custom component with a listener class extending `org.wso2.carbon.user.core.listener.UserOperationEventListener` and implement its `doPreAuthenticate` where you can check the username if it contains the user store domain withing it and `return false` if it does not.

## update

Please refer pulasthi7's answer, seems like `customUserStoreManager` is what we need to implement here, not the listener.

Comment: Writing a custom component is the solution here. However, user operation listener won't work because by the time it reaches the listeners the domain is processed and dropped from the user name, so it should be a custom userstore. see my answer below.

Comment: https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/4.4.x/core/org.wso2.carbon.user.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/user/core/common/AbstractUserStoreManager.java#L458-#L500 here I don't see domain get dropped from username attribute before it reach the preAuthenticate method, so it seems like using the listener method should work. And I believe it'll my less complex than writing custom userStoreManager